# Disable SNMP Status Enabled via Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, snmp, printers

I'm looking to disable the SNMP Status Enabled flag/checkbox for a printer driver using powershell.  The checkbox can be found on Windows 7 under Control Panel -> Devices and Printers ->  -> printer properties -> Ports -> Configure Port

Image of the checkbox desired to toggle to disable status:
[image]

If examples of powershell scripts are available I wish to review them.  I'm unable to find resources in books or online that cover this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works but isn't exactly elegant. It must be run from an elevated prompt. It will loop through all TCP/IP ports and disable SNMP on them if its enabled. You will need to restart (shutdown -t 0 -r) for the setting to be applied however.

```
    dir "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports" | gp "SNMP Enabled" | ?{$_."SNMP Enabled" -eq 1} | %{sp -Path $_.PSPath -Name "SNMP Enabled" -Value 0}

    shutdown -t 0 -r
```

You can also take a look at the [printer cmdlets on server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918357.aspx) or use [portmgr.vbs from MS.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490975.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This post just adds to the good work done by Michael, Bob, and Kevin and combines them into one. It'll also save a copy of the existing settings before it makes changes in case you need to revert back later on.

Also, there is no need to reboot the server - restarting the spooler service is enough:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports' | Out-File -FilePath 'PrinterPortSettings.txt'

Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports' | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name 'SNMP Enabled' -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name 'SNMP Index' -Value 0
}

Get-Service -Name 'Spooler' | Restart-Service -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the answer, I received errors about trying to pipe into gp. Since I just wanted to turn SNMP off for each TCP/IP printer, I shortened the command to

```
dir "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports" | %{sp -Path $_.PSPath -Name "SNMP Enabled" -Value 0}
```

and then rebooted. After doing so, all my connected TCP/IP printers showed SNMP disabled in the port configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Good post.

I just wanted to share that I ran the command above, along with a reboot but it didn't work 100%. I found that also changing *SNMP Index* to 0, in addition to the previous command and reboot did the trick. So my ps command looks as follows (I manually reboot so I don't have that in the command):

```
dir "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports" | %{sp -Path $_.PSPath -Name "SNMP Enabled" -Value 0}
```

dir "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports" | %{sp -Path $_.PSPath -Name "SNMP Index" -Value 0}